# UIButton in cell doesn't change

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UITableView and some custom cells, everything was working fine up until now. I made a custom UITableViewCell class and prototype with a UIButton which I want to give a custom image and text when the cell is loaded into to the table.

**Code background:**

This is in the UITableView controller's `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath)`, the controller has certain data stored in a 'catch' ivar, which in turn has the image to be placed in the button as well as text values. The custom `UITableViewCell` is `ImageTitleTableViewCell`, which merely has the IBOutlet properties as seen below - two labels and the myImageButton UIButton.

```
let cell: ImageTitleTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageTitleCell") as! ImageTitleTableViewCell
//Happily this never triggers.
assert(cell.myImageButton.imageView != nil, "Bad image button.")
cell.myImageButton.imageView!.image = catch.image
if catch.image != nil {
    cell.myImageButton.titleLabel!.text = ""
    println(cell.myImageButton.titleLabel!.text)
    // Always logs the the default value of the button text which isn't "".
} else {
    cell.myImageButton.titleLabel!.text = "None."
}
//These two work fine though.
cell.speciesLabel.text = catch.species
cell.dateLabel.text = catch.date.description
return cell
```

It doesn't ever put in the image either. We can be confident that catch.image does contain a valid UIImage when I test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the image and the text for a button directly. Use the [`func set<X>(forState:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setImage:forState:) and [`func <X>ForState:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/imageForState:) methods.

```
cell.myImageButton.setImage(catch.image, forState:.Normal)
```

and

```
cell.myImageButton.setTitle("", forState:.Normal)
```

The code becomes

```
cell.myImageButton.setImage(catch.image, forState:.Normal)
if catch.image != nil {
    cell.myImageButton.setTitle("", forState:.Normal)
    println(cell.myImageButton.titleForState(.Normal))
    // Always logs the the default value of the button text which isn't "".
} else { 
    cell.myImageButton.setTitle("None.", forState:.Normal)
}
```

Comment: Wow, I can't remember anything without checking the documentation. I used `ControlState` instead of just `State` in the first version of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's clearly /the/ way to do it. Just to clear up, why exactly didn't my way work? The documentation suggests that the properties I was accessing were readwrite and it should have surely worked.

Comment: @RichardBirkett I don't know the internals, but as a guess… a value for `UIControlStateNormal` was set as `nil`, so when the button displayed itself as normal it substituted the `nil`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess what I used only works more "live" rather than in prep.

Answer (score 0):

Use following to update image:

```
cell.myImageButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "imgTest.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

OR for your code:

```
cell.myImageButton.setImage(catch.image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```